# Contiki and CC2531 usb dongle

Tags: contiki

I am working on Contiki-2.7. I have the CC2530dk and want to program the cc2531 usb-dongle. 
My question is how can I upload the hex file from contiki to the Flash programmer, to burn it into the cc2531 usb dongle

For example how to get the hello-world.hex file to upload it in the Flash programmer

Comment: Which wireless sensor mote you are using ? here is [the list of the hardware platforms currently in the Contiki code tree](http://www.contiki-os.org/hardware.html).
And [here](http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html#hardware) how to upload a program on a hardware.

Answer (score 0):

here is a step by step procedure to do it on a USB Dongle

1. cd into the directory of CC2530 in examples

   cd contiki-2.7/examples/cc2530dk
2. make if its the first time to create hex. The hex files here are generated for the CC2530EB

   make
3. if you want it for the cc2531, go into the directory cc2530-usb-demo

   cd contiki-2.7/examples/cc2530dk/cc2530-usb-demo
4. make to produce hex
5. use CC Debugger or the debug converter for the cc2530DK and [SmartRF Flash Programmer](http://www.ti.com/tool/flash-programmer) from TI
6. browse the hex and erase and program